# MySQL General error: 126 Incorrect key file for table '/tmp/#sql_27e6_0.MYI'; try to repair it'

Tags: mysql

I have a table in MySQL with ~2,000,000 rows.

When I try to select all records, it exhausts the system's memory and I get an error about memory exhaustion back.

When I try to use the MySQL `LIMIT` and select 1,000 records, the error in the title is returned:

`General error: 126 Incorrect key file for table '/tmp/#sql_27e6_0.MYI'; try to repair it'`

What's the best course of action to export all of the data in this table?  Why is it returning an error when only trying to pick 1,000 records?

My query:

`select * from notes order by id asc limit 1000`

Comment: How much free disk space do you have in `/tmp` ?

Comment: I monitored it while running the query and it's all eaten up.  Why would it be eaten up trying to select 1,000 and what are my alternatives?

Comment: You're doing an  `ORDER BY`. It has to sort the entire table of 2 million records before giving you the first 1000. That's why

Comment: I need it, is there any way for me to keep it or not?

Answer (score 1):

You can remove any /tmp/#sql* files -- they are tmp tables left over after a crash.  Or they are part of something (ALTER, CREATE, etc) that is going on, but stuck waiting for disk space.

It is often a mistake to have a separate filesystem for tmp -- you run into problems like this:  Plenty of space to finish a task, but not in /tmp.  Consider changing mysql's tmpdir setting.